# What would be the best way to find an event x and an event y in an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Basically I have this array with 'enter' and 'leave' events thats looks something like this.

```
[
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: 2021-02-25T17:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: 2021-02-25T18:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: 2021-02-26T10:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: 2021-02-26T10:14:42.221Z },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: 2021-02-26T12:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: 2021-02-26T12:14:42.221Z }
]
```

The idea is to get 1 enter event and 1 leave event, and in the case where there are more than 1 enter events pick the first one, and where there are more than 1 leave events pick the last one.

With the final intention of having an array that looks like this.

```
[
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: 2021-02-25T17:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: 2021-02-25T18:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: 2021-02-26T10:13:42.221Z },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: 2021-02-26T12:14:42.221Z }
]
```

My idea to approach this, was to have boolean checks that told me if the enter was found and if it was the first one, and if the leave was found and it was the last one. But I think there should be a better way of solving this, any ideas appreciated.

```
calculateTime = async (eventsArr) => {
        console.log('calculating time')
        let enterCheck: Boolean = false;
        let leaveCheck: Boolean = false;
        let lastLeaveCheck: Boolean = false;
        eventsArr.forEach(element => {
            if (!enterCheck && element.event === 'enter' ){
                enterCheck = true;
                console.log('enter found');

            } else if(enterCheck && element.event === 'leave') {
                leaveCheck = true;
            }
        });

            return true
    }
```

Comment: What you posted is not valid JavaScript.  It would help clarify if you could show *exactly* what your array looks like.

Comment: Why in the case of 'leave' event you want to pick from the last one? any reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "get" and "pick"? I'm not sure how you want to create a new array, or manipulate the existing one.

Comment: @shikhar basically i'm going to calculate the time between enter and leave events and the requirements is that it takes the first enter and the last leave is there are many of the same event between them as shown above.

Comment: @Bergi i think its better explained now what im trying to accomplish, im trying to get an array where there is enter event followed by a leave event and it doesnt repeat two enters or two leave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a counter, which increments with *enter* and decrements with *leave*. If after an increment it is 1, or after a decrement it is 0, then the record should be retained, otherwise not:

```js
let arr = [
    { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-25T17:13:42.221Z' },
    { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-25T18:13:42.221Z' },
    { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-26T10:13:42.221Z' },
    { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-26T10:14:42.221Z' },
    { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-26T12:13:42.221Z' },
    { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-26T12:14:42.221Z' },
];

let count = 0;
let result = arr.filter(({event}, i) => {
     let add = +(event == "enter"); 
     count += add || -1;
     return count <= add;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for boolean flags, all you need to do is compare each item to the previous one to decide whether to keep it or not. Only if it's a different event (the first in a new group) than before, you copy it into the new array.

You can do this using `filter`:

```js
const arr = [
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-25T17:13:42.221Z' },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-25T18:13:42.221Z' },
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-26T10:13:42.221Z' },
  { event: 'enter', createdAt: '2021-02-26T10:14:42.221Z' },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-26T12:13:42.221Z' },
  { event: 'leave', createdAt: '2021-02-26T12:14:42.221Z' },
];

const newArr = arr.filter((obj, i) => i==0 || obj.event != arr[i-1].event);
console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: This works for the 'enter' event, but not for the 'leave' event as for the 'leave' event i need the last one instead of the first one you encounter, that's my challenge in this problem

Comment: Oh, right, for that you'll need to compare `enter` events against the previous and `leave` events against the next event. Makes the condition a bit more lengthy, but the approach is the same.